# Google App Engine service with static files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app with a `service` with `app.yaml` file like below:

```
# app.yaml
handlers:
- url: /dist/(.+)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.+)

- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

And there is `dispatch.yaml` to add the service:

```
# dispatch.yaml
dispatch:
  - url: "*/apple/*"
    service: apple
```

But the `apple` service itself, is just a static `html` file with some javascript assets:

```
# apple.yaml
service: apple

handlers:
- url: /dist/(.+)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.+)

- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

The problem is, if I go to `www.example.com/apple` the `main.js` file which is referred to by `index.html` as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/main.js"></script>` is not found and instead `index.html` is returned.

> Refused to execute script from 'https://www.example.com/apple/dist/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

But if I browse the `apple` service directly at `https://apple-dot-example.appspot.com/` it works.

Obviously the problem is how the static fils are routed. Since browser makes the request to `www.example.com/dist/main.js` and the file is actually at `www.example.com/apple/dist/main.js` it's 404ed.

Even If I change the script to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/apple/dist/main.js"></script>`, it doesn't work.

How can I server multiple static directories when I have a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the path you're requesting is actually `/dist/main.js`, which doesn't match the `apple` service dispatch rule pattern: `*/apple/*` - so it gets routed to the `default` service.

To fix it you need to:

- update the patterns in the `apple.yaml` file (which BTW you should call `apple` to match your dispatch service name):

  ```
  # apple.yaml
  service: apple

  handlers:
  - url: /apple/dist/(.+)
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.+)

  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
  ```

  Note that even if the last rule above can match anything it won't actually get requests without an `*/apple/*` in the path because those won't make it to the `apple` service.
- refer to the files using the updated paths, so that the dispatcher can route them to the `apple` service:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/apple/dist/main.js"></script>
  ```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much.